# Get a substring from pyspark DF

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following DF

```
name
Shane
Judith
Rick Grimes
```

I want to generate the following one

```
name           substr
Shane          hane
Judith         udith
Rick Grimes    ick Grimes
```

I tried:

```
F.substring(F.col('name'), 1)
F.substring(F.col('name'), 1, None)
F.substring(F.col('name'), 1, F.length(F.col('name')))
```

But all of those methods throws me an error.

How can I get my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `expr` to get the desired output

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
F.withColumn('substr',expr("substring(name, 2, length(name)-1)"))
```

Comment: I think it should be "substring(name, 2, length(name)-1)" . Just now tried, was about to post.

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: When I use `F.length('name')`  I got the following error `Column is not iterable`

Comment: @OdiumPura Can you try SparkSQL instead of using built-in functions? I updated my answer with import and it's working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

spark documentation for substring states that index is not 0 based

`The position is not zero based, but 1 based index.`

[pyspark.sql.functions.substring](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.substring.html#pyspark.sql.functions.substring)

```
df.withColumn('sub_string', F.expr("substring(name, 2, length(name)-1)"))
```

Comment: When I use `F.length('name')`  I got the following error `Column is not iterable`

Answer (score 1):

`F.substring` takes the integer so it only works if you pass integers.

```
F.substring('name', 2, 5)

# This doesn't work. substring doesn't take Column (F.length()) 
F.substring('name', 2, F.length('name'))
```

If you would like to pass a dynamic value, you can do either SQL's substring or `Col.substr`.

**SQL**

```
F.expr('substring(name, 2, length(name))')
```

**[Col.substr(startPos, length)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.substr.html)**

This will take `Column` (Many Pyspark function returns `Column` including `F.length`) or `int`. Although, startPos and length has to be in the same type. eg: If you need to pass `Column` for length, use `lit` for the startPos.

```
F.col('name').substr(F.lit(2), F.length('name'))

# If you pass integer for both.
# F.col('name').substr(2, 5)
```